# Getting RMagick/ImageMagick gravity with text

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

Here is Ruby code:

```
require 'rmagick'

include Magick

img = Image.new(300, 300)
draw = Draw.new

draw.line(0, 150, 300, 150)
draw.line(150, 0, 150, 300)

# for each of known gravity constants...
%w[NorthWestGravity NorthGravity NorthEastGravity WestGravity CenterGravity EastGravity SouthWestGravity SouthGravity SouthEastGravity].
each{|g|
  # set gravity to this value...
  draw.gravity Magick.const_get(g)
  # ...and draw text with this constant name
  draw.text 150, 150, g
}

draw.draw(img)

img.write('tmp/gravity.png')
```

Here is image which it produces:

[image]

For SouthEast/NorthWest and similar gravities result is as expected (text is near 150,150, moved in desired direction). But for South, North and others result is really pretty weird.

As far as I can understand from code, RMagick just translates gravity and text commands into corresponding ImageMagick drawing primitives, so, I suppose its something in ImageMagick's gravity concept that I can't get.

What is it?..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I suppose its something in ImageMagick's gravity concept that I can't get.
>
> What is it?..

The key to understanding what's going on is to locate the **CenterGravity** text.

[image: Where is Center?]

Shifted left by *150px*, and down by *150px*.

Now compare compare **NorthWestGravity** position.

[image: Where is NorthWest?]

Also translated left & down by *150px* respectively. Seeing a trend?

Your issue is with this line...

```
draw.text 150, 150, g
```

<strike>The `Magick::Draw` API maps to [MVG](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/magick-vector-graphics.php) spec. Use `Magick::Draw.push` & `Magick::Draw.pop` to control drawing context.</strike>

### Edit from comments...

For setting the *origin* of text to be drawing, you'll need to calculate the position after evaluation the text/type metrics.

Example.

```ruby
require 'rmagick'

include Magick

img = Image.new(300, 300) {
  self.background_color = "palegreen"
}
draw = Draw.new
dotes = Draw.new # Dotes added for point of origin
dotes.fill = "red"

cursor = 1
# for each of known gravity constants...
%w[NorthWestGravity NorthGravity NorthEastGravity WestGravity CenterGravity EastGravity SouthWestGravity SouthGravity SouthEastGravity].
each{|g|
  offsetX = 150
  offsetY = cursor * 25
  dotes.circle offsetX, offsetY, offsetX+2, offsetY+2
  # Get metrics of text
  metrics = draw.get_type_metrics(img, g)
  # Full width
  if %w[NorthWestGravity WestGravity SouthWestGravity].include? g then
    offsetX -= metrics[:width]
  end
  # Full height
  if %w[SouthWestGravity SouthGravity SouthEastGravity].include? g then
    offsetY += metrics[:ascent]
  end
  # Half width
  if %w[NorthGravity SouthGravity CenterGravity].include? g then
    offsetX -= metrics[:width] / 2
  end
  # Half height
  if %w[WestGravity CenterGravity EastGravity].include? g then
    offsetY += metrics[:ascent] / 2
  end
  draw.text offsetX, offsetY, g
  cursor += 1
}
dotes.draw(img)
draw.draw(img)

img.write('output.png')
```

[image: gravity with text]

Comment: Wow. It really makes sense now! Thank you :)

Comment: ...And so, for my "expected" result (draw text near some point, but to different directions from it) there's no simple solution, right?..

Comment: Ah, yes it will take some light math work on your end, but nothing that can't be combined into a one-liner subclass.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, I already came with get_type_metrics solution; just wanted to know if it is not an overkill for the task.